# undefined method `latitude' for nil:NilClass "Trying to get columns to call from from a separate table"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, if-statement, model, foreign-keys

**NoMethodError in Pages#home**

**undefined method `latitude' for nil:NilClass**

Trying im getting an error as if latitude column in my database doesnt exist.  the Iframe code works as it extracts the data from the database using post.place.latitude.  i have a foreign key in my place table "place_id" that references my post table.
The error is at the if statement when it gets to latitude. post.place seems to be recognized however all my other columns within places table dont.  Yes i have restarted and refreshed my server and rake db:migrate..

Post form:

```rails
<% if post.place.latitude != nil && post.place.longitude != nil  %>  
    <iframe
    width="600"
    height="450"
    frameborder="0" style="border:0"
    src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=<%="#{post.place.latitude},#{post.place.longitude}" %>&key=AIzaSyC5bK09sEpDbIjFzC4ExUk_EwLkagj7jRo">
</iframe>

<% end %>
```

post model:

```rails
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user



has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
has_one :place, dependent: :destroy, autosave: false

    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates :image, presence: true


accepts_nested_attributes_for :place

  has_attached_file :image, styles: { :medium => "640x" }

  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

after_post_process :save_latlong


private

def save_latlong
  exif_data = MiniExiftool.new(image.queued_for_write[:original].path)
 #place.latitude = parse_latlong(exif_data['gpslatitude'])
  #place.longitude = parse_latlong(exif_data['gpslongitude'])


   update_attributes(
     place_attributes:{latitude: parse_latlong(exif_data['gpslatitude']), 
     longitude: parse_latlong(exif_data['gpslongitude'])}
  )


end

def parse_latlong(latlong)
  return unless latlong
  match, degrees, minutes, seconds, rotation = /(\d+) deg (\d+)' (.*)" (\w)/.match(latlong).to_a
  calculate_latlong(degrees, minutes, seconds, rotation)
end

def calculate_latlong(degrees, minutes, seconds, rotation)
  calculated_latlong = degrees.to_f + minutes.to_f/60 + seconds.to_f/3600
  ['S', 'W'].include?(rotation) ? -calculated_latlong : calculated_latlong
end


end
```

Place model:

```rails
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :post

    validates :post_id, presence: true
end
```

Comment: You can use try to avoid errors like that: `if post.place.try(:latitude) && post.place.try(:longitude)`. Is your code running fine in console?

Comment: wow this worked thank you so much!!! so can i use this to extract and save data into those fields as well??

Comment: In Ruby 2.3 the syntax for save navigation is shortly just: `a&.b`, so you could use something like `post.place&.latitude`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `try` to avoid errors like that:

```
if post.place.try(:latitude) && post.place.try(:longitude)
```

In Ruby 2.3 the syntax for save navigation is shortly just: `a&.b`, so you could use something like `post.place&.latitude`:

```rails
<% if post.place.try(:latitude) != nil && post.place.try(:longitude) != nil  %>
```